# variable 'cmd_part_1' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I keep having this error on my bot program:

> start.py:890 local variable 'cmd_part_1' referenced before assignment

#### Code:

```
try:
    my_alias = message.body.split(" ", 3)
    if len(my_alias) > 2:
        cmd_part_1 = my_alias[0]
        cmd_part_2 = my_alias[1]
    elif len(my_alias) < 2:
        cmd_part_1 = ""
        cmd_part_2 = ""
except Exception as e:
    cmd_part_1 = ""
    cmd_part_2 = ""

if self.getAccess(user.name.lower()) >= lvl_config.rank_req_callme and cmd_part_1 == "call" and cmd_part_2 == "me":
    whole_body = message.body
    whole_body = whole_body.replace("call me ", "");
    whole_body = whole_body.replace(",", "&#44;");
    chat_message("<font color='#%s' face='%s' size='%s'>%s <b>%s</b></font>" % (font_color, font_face, font_size, random.choice(["Recorded! ^_^ I will now call you", "Registah'd, you are now", "Yo, dis mah big homie, I call dem", "Ye-a-a-ah, I guess I can call you that...", "If I have to.. I suppose I'll call you..", "I decided I will call you"]), whole_body), True)
    alias_flag = 0
    finished_proc = 1
    file = open("storage/flatfile/various/aliases.csv", "r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        alias_data = line.strip()
        alias_username, alias_nickname = alias_data.split(",", 1)
```

#### Error Line:

```
if self.getAccess(user.name.lower()) >= lvl_config.rank_req_callme and cmd_part_1 == "call" and cmd_part_2 == "me":
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The indentation for the try and except blocks seem off, and it's unclear whether the rest of the indentation is correct from this snippet.

Comment: I don't think you have to apologize for being Dutch when using Guido van Rossum's language.

Answer (score 3):

You have `if` and `elif` statements in the first `try` block that set `cmd_part_1`.

What happens if none of the conditions in these `if` statements is `True`?

In that case, `cmd_part_1` will never be assigned a value. This is what is going on in your code. Fix this and it will work. Maybe add an `else` clause there and assign a default value to both `cmd_part_1` and `cmd_part_2`. Or make one of them have an `=`.

For example:

```
if len(my_alias) >= 2:
```

instead of:

```
if len(my_alias) > 2:
```

After that, as eryksun suggested in the comment below, you can replace the `elif` with an `else`.

Comment: Probably it should be `if len(my_alias) >= 2` since the assignments  need subscripts 0 and 1. Then if that test is `False`, default to an `else` suite, not an `elif` test.

Comment: @eryksun you are right. I updated my answer based on your suggestion.